# How to bind click events to elements with a specific class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to bind click events on pageload to all elements that have the class "X"
I know that we can mount eventlisteners in the following way, but I can't find out how to do the same for click events. somthing like: `v-on:click="onClick($event)"`or `@click.stop`

This is what I use to for eventlisteners:

```
 mounted:function(){
      this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.onClicked)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass your method on the v-on:click function defined on your HTML tag. See:

```html
<button v-on:click="sendMessage()" value='Send'>Send Message</button>
```

```
methods: {
        sendMessage(e) {
            console.log(`Hello, world from the button ${e.target.value}`)
        },
},

mounted: {
        this.sendMessage()
}
```

Where `e` is the event dispatched when you click the button.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in what I am trying to accomplish. I'm not trying to 'call' functions on page load but I'd like to 'attach' the v-on directive programmatically to elements that have the class 'X'

Comment: Use v-model is not an alternative?

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to dynamically attach a v-on directives to elements in a way that the following is adding classes to an element with a specific ID on page load `window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('about').className = 'expand';
};`

Answer (score -1):

I'll do this the old fashioned way.

Using Jquery (or native JS)

```
$(document).on('click', 'yourCssClass', function(e){
    yourJsCode;
});
```